Asking for PC2 Pin out of LoRa-E5 Development Board from Seeed Studio
I want to assgin MISO pin for LoRa-E5 DevBoard on pin PC2, but it is not possible to find pin PC2 on LoRa-E5 DevBoard from schematic of LoRa-E5 DevBoard, although in Pin Diagram in STM32CubeIDE have shown the pin PC2, where can i find this PC2 pin on LoRa-E5 DevBoard. I can not assign MISO pin for another pin except this pin PC2 on IOC File of LoRa-E5 Chip because of conflict with another pin. I have post schematic of DevBoard LoRa-E5 from Seeed Studio. Link to LoRa-E5 DevBoard Schematic : https://files.seeedstudio.com/products/113990934/LoRa-E5%20Dev%20Board%20v1.0.pdf
Link to documentation of LoRa-E5 Development Board: https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/LoRa_E5_Dev_Board/


You do not give enough information to help, please provide reference and documentation of your dev board.

Which specific board are you using? Do you have a link or a picture?

i have already repost it, i can not post file pdf, only unfulfil picture of the board. You guys can search "LoRa-E5 development board schematic", it have in first result website

what specific explaination should i add to the question ? Can you clarify that ?, I have already explain what problem i met.

I can not find the pin PC2 on LoRa-E5 Development board according to the schematic from Seeed Studio and asking for help ?. I have alredy post the schematic and the pin diagram, also the link for the schematic and documentation of LoRa-E5 DevBoard,
What should i more clarify ?


The reason you can't find the PC2 pin on the dev board is because it isn't available on the module it's based on. The LoRa-E5 module has 28 pins and it uses the STM32WLE5JC which has 73 pins. This means not all pins of the MCU are accessible. The PC2 pin is among the inaccessible pins.

thanks you for your helping
